# facetime:// url scheme

Tags: iphone, facetime

When trying to have my app open a facetime url (facetime://15555555555), it loads up a blank black screen.

```
NSURL *facetimeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://15555555555"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:facetimeURL];
```

Has anyone had any success with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just a heads up that this appears to have been fixed in IOS 4.1, we were having a similar issue in 4.0, but after upgrading to 4.1 - it started working.

The line we used was:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"facetime://5555555555"]];
```

We didn't try with leading 1.